# How to display a text in textArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm trying to display the public key of X.509 certificate in a `textArea` in a GUI instead of using `System.out.println()`. When I tried to display it inside the textArea using `setText()`, it didn't show it inside the `textArea`. The following method `readCertificate` extract the fields of the certificate and `ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` is simply a bottom that activate the action:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    File f = new File("/Users/AhmadAseeri/Desktop/cer.cer");
    Read r = new Read();
    r.readCertificate(f);
}

public void readCertificate(File f) throws Exception {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    while (in.available() > 0) {
        Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(in);
        String c=String.valueOf(cert.getPublicKey());
        JTextArea textArea= new JTextArea();
        textArea.setText(c);  
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Post the compiler exception message or the stacktrace.

Comment: Are you getting a runtime error or a compiler error?

Comment: Try appending text instead or try concatenating a string in the while and setText ouside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a JTextArea but you don't add it to any container.

That way, it will never be shown.

[Here](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-jtextarea-class-example) you can find an example of building a simple GUI with that component.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated:

- You don't add the text area to any container so it will never be visible.
- You create this text area inside the `while` loop which is wrong. You must create the text area and add it to a container when the GUI is initialized.
- You may want to try [append(String str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) method instead of [setText(String str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29).

### In addition

Input-Output operations are time consuming tasks and may block the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (a.k.a. EDT) causing the GUI become unresponsive. To avoid this issue consider use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to perform IO operations in a background thread and update Swing components in the EDT. See more about this matter in [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) trail

#### Example

```
public void readCertificate(final File f) {        
    SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(in);
                String c = String.valueOf(cert.getPublicKey());
                publish(c);
            }
            in.close();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for(String key : chunks) {
                textArea.append(key + System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }            
    };
    worker.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are creating the `textArea` inside the `while` loop, inside the method `readCertificate(File f)`:

```
public void readCertificate(File f) throws Exception {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    while (in.available() > 0) {
        Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(in);
        String c=String.valueOf(cert.getPublicKey());
        JTextArea textArea= new JTextArea();//????????????????????????????????
        textArea.setText(c);  
    }
    in.close();
}
```

You must create it on the frame/panel or when you want, but not there.